# Need to execute SQL queries using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a new task where I need to execute `.sql` files automatically using Jenkins by passing server name and authentication. After long search I found **SQLPlus Script Runner** plugin in Jenkins. As I run my `.sql` files under SQL Server Management Studio I don't think I can use "SQLPlus Script Runner" plugin. Are there any other plugins where I can execute my `.sql` files?

Comment: You can just use a `Bash task` (or however it's called) and run `mysql -uUsername -pPassword Database < file.sql`

Comment: Arent there are any built in plugins to sort this out other than Bash or PowerShell